# Нужно получить url картинки c Reddit через Python

Tags: python

Нужно получить url картинки(если она там есть) из последнего поста определённого сообщества на reddit. Пока не определился с библиотекой, поэтому ничего пока не сделал, но в любом случае не знаю как это реализовать.

Comment: Смотри в сторону `urllib`, `lxml`, `scrapy`. А там, появятся конкретные вопросы, заходи.

Comment: Парсите страницу с помощью `bs4` или `Selenium`.